# How to create an instance of the Model Class in MVC Pattern - SapUI5

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sapui5

I am currently trying to implement the Model-View-Controller in my SAPUI5 / Fiori Project.

I managed to create an Instance of the Controller with: `new sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller('controller.js')`

This does not work for the Model (`sap.ui.core.mvc` does not contain a Model attribute).

Now I am searching a way to call functions of the Model from the Controller, to get my data.

I already tried this code: `oObjModel = new sap.ui.mode.Model()`, using this I cannot call functions from my Model.

Comment: As per my understanding you want to get the data from the controller. With the use of _OData Model_ only you can call the functions. You can refer to [How to consume an OData Service with OpenUI5 / SAPUI5?](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/03/13/how-to-consume-an-odata-service-with-openui5-sapui5/) where on success/failure of the callback you can call the functions as per your requirement. You can use `oModel.read()` to get the data and on success/failure callback you can call your functions

Comment: Yes, I am getting the my Data from an OData Call in the Model. Do some things with it and want to bind it to the View. The Controller should contain the Logic of the Programm. The Problem is that the functions in the Model are not even Called when loading the Page. Not even the `onInit()-Method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look at the [walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) on the SAPUI5 documentation site. It shows how to initialize all the aspects of MVC in the correct way.

---

Models in SAPUI5 come in different classes to support different forms of data. For example, there is `JSONModel`, `XMLModel`, `ODataModel`, etc.

So to create a model, you need to first determine the specific type of model you need and use its specific constructor. For example, if you have JSON data (or simply a JavaScript object), you use the [`JSONModel`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel):

```js
var yourData = { "hello": "world" };
var oModel = new JSONModel(yourData);
```

Note that the above code assumes you are following the recommended way to use modules and that this code is wrapped with a [`sap.ui.define`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.define) or [`sap.ui.require`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.require), where the module `sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel` is assigned to the variable `JSONModel`. [The walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409) shows this correct usage pattern. Accessing the constructor directly like the below is not recommended:

```js
// Also probably works, but not the recommended way
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(yourData);
```

Your way of creating a controller is also not correct. You should preferably let the view instantiate the controller for you by providing it a `controllerName`, as shown in the [walkthrough for Controllers](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/50579ddf2c934ce789e056cfffe9efa9).

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="name.of.your.controller">
    <!-- ... -->
</mvc:View>
```

If you need to manually instantiate a controller from code, use this:

```js
Controller.create({ name: "name.of.your.controller" }).then(function(oController) {
    // Do something with oController
});
```

This again assumes you have the module `sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller` linked to the variable `Controller`.

Before version 1.56, you can use the now-deprecated [`sap.ui.controller`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.controller) function to create controllers instead:

```js
sap.ui.controller("name.of.your.controller", null, /*async=*/true).then(function(oController) {
    // Do something with oController
});
```

Be aware that both of these examples load the controller asynchonously, as [synchronous XHR is being globally deprecated outside of Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request), and thus the framework recommends you to use async only. In fact, the new way of loading does not even provide an option for sync loading.

Comment: How is the Communication between the two Classes handled? Are you suppose to call functions (like get / set Methos) from the other class or just use the Model functions like `Model.read(), update() etc.`? I mean there has to be a way how data ist exchanged and updated through both classes. Is it even eight that I do the oData call in the Model?

Comment: When you create a specific model, you can use the methods of that model on the object that you have. eg. if you have `var oModel = new ODataModel(...)`, then you can use the methods from the ODataModel on the object: `oModel.read(...)`. Although for ODataModel specifically, I believe it will automatically load its data if you bind it to controls in the view.

Comment: To be more specific, I have a working Application with data binding with JSON Models to the View and callback to the SAP with the correct OData Model. Everything is working, the problem is that I coded everything in the Controller ... The oData CAll, the data management etc. ... From my understanding this has to go in the Model but I don't really understand how to use the Model Class. I cant call functions and not even the generic functions like `onInit()` are working

Comment: @LukasMetzger I'm not sure what `onInit` you are referring to, if not the one from the controller. In SAPUI5, models are nothing more than data containers for your data. You create them, set data to them and read it again, nothing more. I guess they are not really traditional "MVC Models" in that sense. The controller is indeed the place to contain all your logic; so if it is already in there it sound to me your application is correct.

Comment: Ok, now it gets more clear to me **thank you**. Is the binding (to the view) also happening from the controller? Because in SAP Presentations of the MVC, there is always a connection between Model and View. Is this just the binding, done in the controller?

Comment: @LukasMetzger Yes, the only connection between the view and the model is the data binding, which can be one-way or two-way. The idea is that the controller creates the model and binds it to the view. The view automatically uses the binding to load the data from the model as needed. A two-way binding can also cause the view to update, but this is something that happens behind the scenes (the framework takes care of it). This usually happens if the data in the model is updated, due to the controller manipulating it in some way.

Comment: But why is a Model Class even needed in this case? The Models from the oData Call, as well as all JSON Models used, will automatically update in the controller, as well as the Model.  I don't really see the purpose of putting them in a separate container? (This question is based on the fact that I have a working application without a Model class and beeing a little bit confused about what (and why) to put in a Model class, because everything is synchron no matter what?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean. By the term "model" do you refer to the SAPUI5 classes (JSONModel etc), or the data contained inside them (like a JS object)? In terms of SAPUI5, a "model" refers _only_ to the former. And their only real purpose is to wrap around the actual data in order to allow for data binding to a view. I would love to keep helping you trying to figure this out, but comments are not an ideal medium for this. Perhaps it is better to search for a more SAP focussed forum like https://community.sap.com

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. I meant the purpose of the Model.js file, sry if that was not clear.

Comment: Ah, you mean the `models.js` file? That seems to be a convention on SAP Cloud Platform (with the Web IDE). I guess the idea is simply to keep creation of models centralized to one file, so that all controllers have easy access to them. You don't really need that file in your project, it should work fine without it (I never used it myself).

Comment: Yes, **thank you** !! Sadly I don't get the model.js to execute when starting the application .... But thanks so much